# Cannot find symbol class error in Android Studio

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio

I have a problem in which I open an old project and I get the errors below. I searched on internet how to solve it. The project already has dependencies with Facebook but I don't know why it doesn't appear in modules (automatic gradle) and when i try to import a new facebook sdk, it tells me that i already have a Facebook module... Anyone with the same problem?

```
   Error:(26, 20) error: cannot find symbol class Request
   Error:(27, 20) error: cannot find symbol class Session
   Error:(28, 20) error: cannot find symbol class SessionState
   Error:(29, 20) error: cannot find symbol class UiLifecycleHelper
   Error:(30, 26) error: package com.facebook.model does not exist
   Error:(31, 27) error: package com.facebook.widget does not exist
   Error:(110, 13) error: cannot find symbol class UiLifecycleHelper
   Error:(111, 20) error: package Session does not exist
   Error:(540, 45) error: cannot find symbol class Session
```

Gradle:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/repo' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.2'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/repo' }
}

android {
compileOptions { sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7 }

compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion '22'
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName '0.85.1.0'
    applicationId 'com.xxxxx'
    multiDexEnabled = true

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
signingConfigs {
    debug {
        storeFile file('keys/debug.keystore')


   }
    release {
        storeFile file('keys/xxx.jks')
        storePassword 'xxx'
        keyAlias 'xxx'
        keyPassword 'xxx'
    }
//        debug {
//            storeFile file("keys/debug.keystore")
//        }
}
productFlavors {
    local {
        resValue "string", "URL", 'xxx'
        resValue "string" , "Debug", '1'
        versionName = android.defaultConfig.versionName + "_local"

    }
    remote {
        resValue "string", "URL", 'xxx'
        resValue "string" , "Debug", '0'
        versionName = android.defaultConfig.versionName + "_remote"

    }
}
defaultConfig {
    testApplicationId "com.xxx.test"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
}
productFlavors {
}
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def outputFile = output.outputFile
            if (outputFile != null && outputFile.name.endsWith('.apk')) {
                def apk = outputFile;
                def newName;

                newName = apk.name.replace(".apk",  variant.name +"-v" + defaultConfig.versionName + "_" + variant.name + ".apk")
                        .replace(project.name, "xxx");

//                    newName = newName
//                            .replace("-" + variant.buildType.name, "")
//                            .replace(project.name, "xxx");

                //output.outputFile = new File(apk.parentFile, newName);
                if (output.zipAlign) {
                    //variant.outputFile = new File(apk.parentFile, newName.replace("-unaligned", ""));
                    newName = newName.replace("-unaligned", "");
                }

                //def fileName = outputFile.name.replace('.apk', "-${versionName}.apk")
                output.outputFile = new File(outputFile.parent, newName)

                logger.info('INFO: Set outputFile to ' + output.outputFile + " for [" + output.name + "]");
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
//    compile project(':facebook')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.0'
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:7.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.3.0'

compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'

compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile project(':PuntechSensorsLib')

compile ("com.doomonafireball.betterpickers:library:1.5.3") {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.0.1@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
}

ext.betaDistributionGroupAliases="internal"
```

Comment: Have you imported an Eclipse project into AS?

Comment: mmmm i'm not sure, inside the folder had already .gradle but when i open for first time, tell me than will use default sdk and the gradle settings are not configured yet if i want use wrapper or manually...

Comment: sorry i update the errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of conflicts in your XML files.

As the errors tell you, several xml files (in your res folders, maybe "attr" ones but I cannot be sure) has the same name in different projects.

Maybe they belong to your definitions or third's, but the ID for your resources must be unique.

Try checking if they can be yours and rename them.

EDIT:

Now I can see your errors,

Add jcenter() to your repos. Facebook artifacts seem to be there. You don't need to remove your previous one.

In your repositories zone:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()       // IntelliJ main repo.
}
```

In case you already have a "facebook" module, remove it from your project structure (file -> project structure) and you can also delete your module files in case you want to clean your project. (**attention**: all of this only if you didn't customize anything from "facebook" module").

With gradle, you only need import it from your build.gradle, and not having your own "facebook" module.

Comment: i add it, same error, as i said i don't know why facebook library dosn't appear on project structure module, and if i try to add it tell me than it's already a module with Facebook name. Thanks for the fast responses both!

Comment: I edited my answer again. I hope this would help you.-

Answer (score 0):

When I was using `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'` I had the same problem. I used `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.23.1'` instead and my project was built successfully. I do not know if it has something to do with upgrading from 3.x to 4.0.